# How to map path elements to method parameter in spring cloud function web

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-cloud-function

I'm working on a Microservice that receives webhooks, the idea is to use path variables for some processing down stream,

/webhooks/{foo}/{bar}/{baz}

for example

`/webhooks/sony/pony/tony` would populate `foo=sony`; `bar=pony`; `baz=tony`.

Can't figure how to make it work in spring cloud function web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was never the purpose of spring-cloud-function to replace spring-mvc etc.
Also, Function has only one argument, so what you can do is have `Function<Message, ...>` and we translate HTTP request into Message where `body` will turn into `payload` and `HTTP headers` will turn into `Message headers`.

Comment: Can't send headers as this url typically receives web hooks from Gitlab and Jira etc. I switched to a webflux endpoint calling stream bridge.